# What's the function of these 7 lines SQL?

Tags: sql

## Update

Don't read this question. It's a mistake. I should not answer this question. 
I try to delete it, but stackoverflow don't let me do it.
I am sorry for wasting your time if you read this.

## Origin

I just find these sql example which I don't understand. Does anyone know what are these codes doing?

```
delete t1
from [table] t1
where 
(
    select [c] 
    from [table] t2 
    where t1.[c] <> t2.[c]
) > 0
```

Comment: It deletes the non matching records in table t1 from table t2

Comment: Change `delete` to `select *`. I'm surprised that doesn't error for returning multiple rows in the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select [c] 
from [table] t2 
where t1.[c] <> t2.[c]
```

is a subquery. To be more specific, it is a scalar subquery. Scalar subqueries allow you to treat the output of a subquery as a column or even an expression within a SELECT statement. It is a query that only selects one column or expression and returns just one row. If the scalar subquery fails to return any rows, the database engine will use a NULL value for the output of the scalar subquery.

So, your overall query is the same as this sentence:

> delete all such records from [table] (let's call it now t1) that match
>   the criteria:
>
> let's take a value of column [c] in the row, then try to search such
>   row in [table] (let's call it t2 now, just forget that it's the same
>   table) that has value for column t2.c that is different from the value
>   of t1.c that we had taken before. If we find such row in t2, then
>   let's take the value of the column t2.[c] and compare it to zero.

It's a complex query for understanding. The problem is that you use in subquery the same table for comparison. Also the weird comparison to zero at the end, that just does not make sense.

You can try to improve your question giving meaningful table and column names. Now it is hard to explain to anyone, hard to understand for you.

Comment: Now I feel stupid, I thought it's some clever code which I don't understand. Can I just delete this question so it will not waste time of more people, if you would allow me?

Comment: Sure you can do )